# Set nautilus up action to backspace

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome3, nautilus, backspace

I use arch linux. I had changed the Up action of nautilus from Alt+left arrow to Backspace. But after a full update, it reverted back to Alt+left.

I checked the file '~/.config/nautilus/accels' but it is still set as Backspace.

The nautilus version is 3.16.1.

I have tried commenting it and then uncomment it again after rebooting. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See bottom for updates with a great workaround**

No suggestions but I did report this to them as a bug a while back. Basically the response is that they don't agree with Backspace therefore no one should be able to use it as their hotkey.

[Here's my bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750107)

This wouldn't be as annoying if there was a way to customize the hotkeys. Unfortunately that was also removed as they switched over to a new framework for managing the key-to-action mapping. Theoretically they'll bring back a way to customize it but I wouldn't hold your breath. It certainly won't end up in 3.16.

Here's two more bug reports for good measure [1](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692648) [2](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752277)

[Bug I just submitted asking for a way to configure keyboard shortcuts](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752666)

---

Ok so things have changed somewhat and I may have a solution if you're up to it. I have written a patch which returns the Backspace as up functionality.

I don't know what the procedure is for obtaining and building the source for a package is on Arch but as an Arch user you probably already know that part.

So here is the patch

```
--- src/nautilus-window.c   2015-07-31 10:18:29.313898480 -0400
+++ src/nautilus-window.c   2015-07-31 10:21:20.701351684 -0400
@@ -565,7 +565,7 @@
    nautilus_application_add_accelerator (app, "win.redo", "<shift><control>z");
    /* Only accesible by shorcuts */
    nautilus_application_add_accelerator (app, "win.bookmark-current-location", "<control>d");
-   nautilus_application_add_accelerator (app, "win.up", "<alt>Up");
+   nautilus_application_add_accelerator (app, "win.up", "BackSpace");
    nautilus_application_add_accelerator (app, "win.go-home", "<alt>Home");
    nautilus_application_add_accelerator (app, "win.tab-previous", "<control>Page_Up");
    nautilus_application_add_accelerator (app, "win.tab-next", "<control>Page_Down");
```

I hope this helps

---

**Another update**: A github user by the username of riclc has figured out (quite ingeniously) that the keybindings can be altered by a nautilus-python plugin and has provided the code to allow for backspace-up [here](https://github.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace). This means no more patching and recompiling, just drop his script in the right place and you will always have backspace for up!